# C# Linq to datagrid with update functionality

Tags: c#, linq, datagrid

I wanted to do a datagrid that had the allowed a user to edit current information as well as add new stuff. I also need it to have a checkbox in there that I can respond to. Basically it would be a name, and an isActive field that was represented by a checkbox in each row of the datagrid.

I would like to use linq for this but am not sure if it's even possible. This is a ASP.Net website.

If anyone had any feedback that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough to do.

The GridView has a number of events that you can use for certain operations (Delete, Edit, Cancel, and Update). For example, the OnRowUpdating and OnRowEditing would look like thus:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTest" runat="Server" OnRowUpdating="gvTest_RowUpdating" OnRowEditing="gvTest_RowEditing">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="Server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update">
        <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="Server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit">
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then implement the event handlers for the update (edit, delete, etc.) in your codebehind. To make life easier for yourself, you can switch over to Design view, find your GridView and bring up the Events (the icon that looks like a lightning bolt) and then double click an event and the stub of it will automatically be created for you in the codebehind and the html markup will automatically be created as well. An example of the RowUpdating event handler would look like thus:

```
protected void gvTest_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) {
  // Convenient access to the row index that was selected
  int theRowIndex = e.RowIndex;
  GridViewRow gvr = gvTest.Rows[e.RowIndex];

  // Now its just a matter of tracking down your various controls in the row and doing 
  // whatever you need to with them
  TextBox someTxtBox = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("theTextBoxID");
  DropDownList someDDL = (DropDownList)gvr.FindControl("theDDL_ID");

  // Perhaps some business class that you have setup to take the value of the textbox
  // and insert it into a table
  MyDoSomethingClass foo = new MyDoSomethingClass {
    FirstName = someTxtBox.Text,
    Age = someDDL.SelectedItem.Value
  };

  foo.InsertPerson();
}
```

Note that you can also use the OnRowCommand instead of using Update (Edit, Delete, etc.) events, but the OnRowCommand doesn't have the selected row index readily available for you. If you want it then you have to do a little magic in your markup.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDoSomething" runat="Server" Text="Do Something" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" CommandName="DoSomething">
```

And then in the RowCommand event you do something like this to get at the row index:

```
protected void gvTest_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) {
  int rowIdx = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Accessing the key(s) that your GridView is bound to is quite simple, actually. Assuming that your GridView is bound to only one key, you can get the key in this manner (assume that we're in the RowCommand event):

```
int rowIdx = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
int someKeyID = Convert.ToInt32(gvTest.DataKeys[rowIdx].Value);
```

Comment: I'm getting 'GridViewUpdateEventArgs does not contain a definition for RowIndex'

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to this. You say that I can find controls, do I just add the controls via the template? I need to display a name and an isActive field and that's pretty much it. I want them to be able to edit stuff and delete it.

Comment: @Blake - I'm not sure why the RowIndex property isn't available to you. It's been a property of EventArgs since the GridView came out with ASP.NET 2.0. Which framework are you on?

Comment: @Jagd sorry I haven't responded sooner. It's .net 4 and I'm not sure why either to be honest. I don't want to recreate this entire project because it is quite large and a pain in the @$$ to setup. If you have any suggestions that would be great. Even building a custom one would be fine.

Comment: The only thing I can think to suggest is to edit your original question and include some of the code, and maybe that will shed some light on things. GL!

Comment: I don't know what's up with it before. it's doing the rowindex now. I'm using
 
[code]int rowIndexHolder = e.RowIndex;[/code]

That gives me the rowindex... but - I need the id of the row it represents in the db. Meaning even if the rowindex is 0... the id for that database row may be 6. I need to grab that. I got it databound off of the linq query (which included the id field that I want) but I don't know how to access it when I catch the event.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: I think that will work :) - I haven't tested it yet, but thank you for your response! I will test in in a bit.